# how can I parse the google books api and access the class properties (vb.net)

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I'm trying to access Googles book api and just populate textboxes with the information.
Here's an example of the API json: [https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:9780979799006]

I used Visual Studio's Paste Special to create the Class.  Here it is:

```
Public Class GoogleBookData

    Public Class Rootobject
        Public Property kind As String
        Public Property totalItems As Integer
        Public Property items() As Item
    End Class

    Public Class Item
        Public Property kind As String
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property etag As String
        Public Property selfLink As String
        Public Property volumeInfo As Volumeinfo
        Public Property saleInfo As Saleinfo
        Public Property accessInfo As Accessinfo
        Public Property searchInfo As Searchinfo
    End Class

    Public Class Volumeinfo
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property subtitle As String
        Public Property publishedDate As String
        Public Property description As String
        Public Property industryIdentifiers() As Industryidentifier
        Public Property readingModes As Readingmodes
        Public Property pageCount As Integer
        Public Property printType As String
        Public Property categories() As String
        Public Property maturityRating As String
        Public Property allowAnonLogging As Boolean
        Public Property contentVersion As String
        Public Property panelizationSummary As Panelizationsummary
        Public Property imageLinks As Imagelinks
        Public Property language As String
        Public Property previewLink As String
        Public Property infoLink As String
        Public Property canonicalVolumeLink As String
    End Class

    Public Class Readingmodes
        Public Property text As Boolean
        Public Property image As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Panelizationsummary
        Public Property containsEpubBubbles As Boolean
        Public Property containsImageBubbles As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Imagelinks
        Public Property smallThumbnail As String
        Public Property thumbnail As String
    End Class

    Public Class Industryidentifier
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property identifier As String
    End Class

    Public Class Saleinfo
        Public Property country As String
        Public Property saleability As String
        Public Property isEbook As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Accessinfo
        Public Property country As String
        Public Property viewability As String
        Public Property embeddable As Boolean
        Public Property publicDomain As Boolean
        Public Property textToSpeechPermission As String
        Public Property epub As Epub
        Public Property pdf As Pdf
        Public Property webReaderLink As String
        Public Property accessViewStatus As String
        Public Property quoteSharingAllowed As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Epub
        Public Property isAvailable As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Pdf
        Public Property isAvailable As Boolean
    End Class

    Public Class Searchinfo
        Public Property textSnippet As String
    End Class
End Class
```

I call this function to read the stream and get the Class data:
Public Shared Function getGoogleBookData(ByVal sSku As String) As GoogleBookData

```
    Dim result As String = Nothing
    Dim url As String = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:"
    url &= sSku

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim reader As StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim myJson As String = Nothing
    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    myJson = reader.ReadToEnd    

    Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim myGBookData As New GoogleBookData
    myGBookData = serializer.Deserialize(Of GoogleBookData)(myJson)
    Return myGBookData

End Function
```

I call the function:

```
Dim gsSearchSku as String = "9780979799006"
Dim myGItem As New GoogleBookData
myGItem = getGoogleBookData(gsSearchSku)
```

Then, I've tried several things to try to access any data in the Class:
I know this doesn't work but put it here so you can get an idea of what I'm trying.

```
Dim sTitle as String = myGItem.Item.Title
```

I can't even run it.  GoogleBookData.item is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.
No idea where to go from here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Deserialize it to a `Rootobject` instead of a `GoogleBookData`.

Comment: @David - Thanks for the idea.  Would it be possible for you to modify the statement I have that is wrong so I can see what you mean?  Also, what would be my statement to get txtItemTitle.text = ??  Thanks!

Comment: `Dim myGBookData = serializer.Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(myJson)` would be to serialize the data and `txtItemTitle.Text = myGBookData.items(0).volumeInfo.title` would be to get the first item's volumeInfo's title.

Comment: You have other problems there. The first is that you have `Option Strict` unfortunately `OFF`; the other is that your properties (a misleading VB.Net *thing*) are declared as single objects instead of arrays. For example, this: `Public Property items() As Item` defines a single object of Type `Item`. To get an array of Items, you need `Public Property items As Item()`. The same goes for the other Properties that should define collections. -- Then, deserialize as `GoogleBookData.Rootobject` and make your method return the same Type.

Comment: This worked.  Could not have done it without both of you!  Got runtime errors when I failed to change all array properties (Thanks for @Jimi for that).  Changed the 2 statements `Dim myGBookData as New GoogleBookData and myGBookData = serializer...` to `Dim myGBookData = serializer.deserialize(Of GoogleBookData.Rootobject)(myJson)`  Also, had to change the function to return `As GoogleBookData.Rootobject`.  Then, when I called the function I could reference the title exactly as @David stated.  Perfect!  Thank you both so much!

Comment: Sorry to be needy (I actually like this json stuff, just don't understand it).  How would I access the part of json that is ` "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "0802412432"
          },`    I tried `= myGItem.item(0).volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers("ISBN_10").identifier`  but it appears to be needing an integer (index to the array, I guess), but I'm wondering how I would know what's in the array.

Comment: As you have specified the indexer in `items(0)` (the Property Name is `items`), the same goes for `industryIdentifiers`. Do you mean you want to retrieve the `identifier` property value of an Item where the `type` property value is `ISBN_10`? Do you know LINQ a bit?

Comment: Yes to your question, I want to grab the identifier (if there) for one of the "types."  And, I can't even spell LINQ (guess I can!).    btw, my name is Link (should have looked into LINQ.

Comment: With LINQ, could be `dim isbn10Id = myGItem.items(0).volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers.FirstOrDefault(Function(iid) iid.type = "ISBN_10")?.identifier`, using the Array methods, e.g., `Array.Find()`, it could be `dim isbn10Id = Array.Find(myGItem.items(0).volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, Function(iid) iid.type = "ISBN_10")?.identifier`. So, give or take, the same thing :) -- `Function(iid) iid.type = "ISBN_10"` is an in-lined predicate (in the second example). I won't tell you the name of the similar Function in the first example :)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant cause I got lost at the ?.identifier.  But, maybe this is what you meant (and it works) `Dim isbn10Id = Array.Find(myGItem.items(0).volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers, Function(iid) iid.type = "ISBN_10")`  then `txtIsbn10.Text = isbn10Id.identifier`    [ Didn't try the LINQ part since that seems more involved.  Thanks again for so much info (didn't solve your puzzle, though!)